# Docker image with python3, chromedriver, chrome & selenium

Tags: python, selenium, docker, selenium-chromedriver, containers

My objective is to scrape the web with [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) driven by [Python](https://www.python.org/) from a [docker](https://www.docker.com/) [container](https://www.docker.com/resources/what-container).

I've looked around for and not found a docker image with all of the following installed:

- [Python 3](https://www.python.org/)
- [ChromeDriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/)
- [Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/)
- [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/)

Is anyone able to link me to a [docker image](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image/) with all of these installed and working together?

Perhaps building my own isn't as difficult as I think, but it's alluded me thus far.

Any and all advice appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium.

It has python installed:

```
$ docker run selenium/standalone-chrome python3 --version
Python 3.5.2
```

The instructions indicate you start it with

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 --shm-size=2g selenium/standalone-chrome
```

**Edit:**

To allow selenium to run through python it appears you need to install the packages. Create this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM selenium/standalone-chrome

USER root
RUN wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
RUN python3 get-pip.py
RUN python3 -m pip install selenium
```

Then you could run it with

```
docker build . -t selenium-chrome && \
    docker run -it selenium-chrome python3
```

The advantage compared to the plain `python` docker image is that you won't need to install the chromedriver itself since it comes from `selenium/standalone-chrome`.

Comment: Thanks Harald - this image puzzles me though since "from selenium import webdriver" leads to "ImportError: No module named 'selenium'" - I'm sure this is my unfamiliarity with what I'm dealing with, but I was expecting this python package to be installed. Do I need to take care of this install with my dockerfile, do you know?

Comment: That puzzles me a bit as well. I'm guessing that python is installed on that image just as a side-effect and not the main point. The user might want to install bindings for Java instead, for example. I updated my answer with instructions to install the python packages, hopefully that helps!

Comment: It works! Thanks Harald, I've been trying to crack this for a long time now. I now get "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH." when trying to run it, but think I've solved this one before. Cheers! :)

Comment: I would gladly help you with the other one if you open a new question :)

Comment: Thanks Harald, I'll link you to a new question if I get stuck :)

Comment: Hi Harald, I managed to solve that last problem, but something related came up that I suspect you'll be able to help me with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47977620/developing-scraping-script-on-docker-image-how-to-overcome-lack-of-visual-brow

Cheers either way.

Answer (score 10):

I like Harald's solution.
However, as of 2021, my environment needed some modifications.

```
Docker version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88
```

I changed the Dockerfile as follows.

```
FROM selenium/standalone-chrome

USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install python3-distutils -y
RUN wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
RUN python3 get-pip.py
RUN python3 -m pip install selenium
```

Comment: This gives me python 3.8 instead of python 3.9 with standalone-chrome:4.9.1

Answer (score 3):

https://hub.docker.com/r/joyzoursky/python-chromedriver/

It uses python3 as base image and install chromedriver, chrome and selenium (as a pip package) to build. I used the alpine based python3 version for myself, as the image size is smaller.

```
$ cd [your working directory]
$ docker run -it -v $(pwd):/usr/workspace joyzoursky/python-chromedriver:3.6-alpine3.7-selenium sh
/ # cd /usr/workspace
```

See if the images suit your case, as you could pip install selenium with other packages together by a `requirements.txt` file to build your own image, or take reference from the Dockerfiles of this.

---

If you want to pip install more packages apart from selenium, you could build your own image as this example:

First, in your working directory, you may have a `requirements.txt` storing the package versions you want to install:

```
selenium==3.8.0
requests==2.18.4
urllib3==1.22
... (your list of packages)
```

Then create the Dockerfile in the same directory like this:

```
FROM joyzoursky/python-chromedriver:3.6-alpine3.7

RUN mkdir packages
ADD requirements.txt packages
RUN pip install -r packages/requirements.txt
```

Then build the image:

```
docker build -t yourimage .
```

This differs with the selenium official one as selenium is installed as a pip package to a python base image. Yet it is hosted by individual so may have higher risk of stopping maintenance.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for sharing your image. I have built my own image in almost the same way you did, but to make selenium tests run, I need to create a `ChromeDriver` with the `--no-sandbox` option and I would like to avoid it.
Could you please tell me if it's possible? I think I have understood that this option is needed because linux launches chrome as root but I am not sure if I totally got the point.