# Python script with Selenium and Chromedriver onto a Docker

Tags: python, docker, selenium, dockerfile, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to have a Docker on my NAS running every 3-4 hours taking a screenshot of a website. Unfortunately, I'm not that familiar with Docker, and I have been searching online and trying to find images that already do what I want without much success. Some work, some others don't, and all the other threads I found here, didn't work either - maybe it was my own fault!

Here is my Python script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from datetime import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait  # for implicit and explict waits
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options  # for suppressing the browser
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.ShowWindow( ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleWindow(), 0 )

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument('headless')
option.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")

CHROME_DRIVER_PATH = (
    "...\chromedriver.exe"
)
URL = "https://www.example.com"
IMAGE_EXT = ".png"


def get_web_driver(driver_path: str) -> webdriver:
    return webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, options=option)


def open_url(web_driver: webdriver, url: str) -> None:
    # opens the given URL
    return web_driver.get(url)
    



def screen_shot_webpage(web_driver: webdriver) -> None:
    time.sleep(3)
    web_driver.get_screenshot_as_file(get_date_today() + IMAGE_EXT)


def get_date_today() -> str:
    now = datetime.now()
    dt_string = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H %M")
    return str(dt_string)


def close_driver(web_driver) -> None:
    web_driver.close()


def main():
    chrome_driver = get_web_driver(CHROME_DRIVER_PATH)
    open_url(chrome_driver, URL)
    screen_shot_webpage(chrome_driver)
    close_driver(chrome_driver)    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I tried creating my own Dockerfile and it was kind of a disaster. I also tried a couple of alternatives from this post to no avail: [Docker image with python3, chromedriver, chrome & selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47955548/docker-image-with-python3-chromedriver-chrome-selenium)

Does anyone have a simple solution for this or is it very complicated? My programming knowledge is very limited :/

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What's your problem? What steps did you do to run? What is your `Dockerfile`? And did you get any errors? Edit the question and add more information.